# How to design dag for different scheduler start time

Tags: python, airflow

1. The problem is

   > if task_1(a1.py) run at 1:00 pm daily, task_2(a2.py) run at 5:00 pm daily, task_3 dependents task_1 and task_2.

How to design them in one dag?

2. I tried that when I set different `schedule_interval` at a task level, it showed warnings like

   > 'schedule_interval was on efficacious as dag level '
3. The code which I have used.

   ```
   from datetime import datetime, timedelta

   from airflow import DAG
   from airflow import utils



   default_args = {
       'owner': 'airflow',
       'depends_on_past': True,
       'start_date': utils.dates.days_ago(2)
   }
   dag = DAG(DAG_NAME, default_args=default_args)

   task_1 = BashOperator(
       task_id='task_1',
       bash_command='python3 a1.py',
       schedule_interval = '0 1 * * *'
       dag=dag,
   )

   task_2 = BashOperator(
       task_id='task_2',
       bash_command='python3 a2.py',
       schedule_interval = '0 5 * * *'
       dag=dag,
   )

   task_3 = BashOperator(
       task_id='task_3',
       bash_command='python3 a3.py',
       dag=dag,
   )

   [task1, task2] >> task3
   ```
4. I am expecting this,

   > 1. task_3 wait for task_1 and task_2 finished, and then start running.
   > 2. task_1, task2, task_3 must be designed in one dag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add [TimeDeltaSensor](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/sensors/time_delta_sensor.html) to wait with timedelta of the minutes between the tasks.

The other option is to create a delaytask using PythonOperator(`time.sleep()`) or BashOperator(`bashcommand='sleep 10m'`) between the 2 task's.

Comment: could i commbine TimeDeltaSensorOperator and BashOperator into a new operator? The new operator have 2 functions that sleep and bashcommand.